# Download a binary file from a z/OS UNIX System Services (USS) file system

Tags: unix, mainframe, zos

I have a file in UTF-8 encoding with a certificate on z/OS in a UNIX file system and I would like to download it using a secure protocol.

I tried to download it using `scp` but the encoding has been automatically converted and the file was not readable.

How can I download the file as binary without changing the encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Zowe CLI](https://github.com/zowe/zowe-cli) to download/upload from z/OS:

```
zowe zos-files download uss-file <path-to-your-file> --binary
```

Alternatively, you can choose your local file name:

```
zowe zos-files download uss-file <path-to-your-file> --binary --file yourFile.bin
```

Upload via:

```
zowe files upload file-to-uss yourFile.bin "<path-to-your-file>/yourFile.bin” --binary
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use `sftp` to access the mainframe then the file is transferred as binary without being converted from EBCDIC to ASCII.

`>sftp mainframe`

`>cd directory/with/certificate`

`>get certificate.cer`
`